# How to use Bcrypt.Net inside vba to authenticate against password stored by crypt function in PHP

Tags: .net, vba, vb.net, ms-access, dll

I have a DB that has stored passwords that where encrypted using PHP's crypt function. I have found out that the crypt function actually uses bcrypt and i have found http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/  bcrypt is written in a very specific way with the BSD Base64 Alphabet not the regular Base64 Alphabet.

I'm hopping the Bcrypt.Net project emulates the PHP verion. but i don't know any thing about using DLLs in side of VBA and being able to access their function. And I don't know how to find the function inside the Dll that emulates the Bcrypt.

Im using the VBA inside Access 2010. Can anyone PLEASE HELP!

Comment: How about this? http://www.di-mgt.com.au/cryptoBlowfishVer6.html

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to use BCrypt in Access unless that .DLL has specifically been written for COM consumers. Most .NET projects/DLL's haven't been written as COM Callable, unless that was a specific requirement when building the .DLL. This is because making DLL's in .NET so they are COM callable is not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded bcrypt.net from here [Bcrypt.Net](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/downloads/get/761250).
To add dll file **right click** on project name and then select "**References...**".
A window will open and then **browse** your dll file to insert. Then add the code as your need in you C# page.

```
using BCrypt;
public partial class your_class_name : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string salt = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt(); //Generate Salt
        string hash = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword("subinoy", salt); //Using salt to generate password
        if(BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify("username","$2a$10$ljfI1o3m3gI.rXDpDkGc/ebUNqHKJ22EhJrQJnuoe3yAf58QoZW6i")) //this hash inside the if() will be taken from the database when the user registered
            bcrypttext.Text = "equals";
        else
            bcrypttext.Text = "Not equal" + hash;
  }
}
```

and for [php **bcrypt**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php) you watch this link

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an extremely old question, however, I have found this for hashing and verifying password hashes created using BCrypt.

https://github.com/as08/ClassicASP.Bcrypt

I was able to register the DLL to a TLB by navigating to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 and running the following command:

```
RegAsm path/to/dllfile/ClassicASP.Bcrypt.dll /tlb /codebase
```

From there, I could use this with late binding:

```
Dim Bcrypt As Object
Set Bcrypt = CreateObject("ClassicASP.Bcrypt")

Dim response

' Generate a hash with a default work factor of 10
response = Bcrypt.Hash("testpassword")
Debug.Print response

'' Verify a hash
response = Bcrypt.Verify("testpassword", "$2a$10$z7vfvfvHkOvJ6H1qMd8G9.kc38zptoqrqpsg/pwYTlmCd37OZ3sDK")
Debug.Print response
```

I was able to verfiy passwords made using the nodejs bcryptjs package.

I hope this helps someone else with the same problem